# MFmail composer sent junk mail with

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I am sending mail using `MFMailComposeViewController` and if i am sending message body with `HTML` tag it will send as a junk mail otherwise it will be sent as a normal mail....

Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

-Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like the issue is with the spam filter on the email account you are receiving with.

Comment: @MDT but If i'll remove html body then it will be not junk.........

Comment: Exactly, the sending device does not determine wether or not the mail it sends is junk mail, the receiving device does.